# Calling a webservice with exectution time > 10 seconds in a loop

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I have a web service in PHP that fetches data from another server. I store all the data from the DB and this takes approx 15 to 20 seconds on every execution. The problem is that when I have to run the service within a date range i.e. for example `01-DEC-2016` to `05-DEC-2016`, the script can run for only one day at a time. I am reluctant to call it in a loop because I have heard that the loop itself executes very fast, while the process itself takes 20 seconds or more. Can  anybody help me?

Comment: its not about log, its about script execution time vs loop execution time

Comment: Why is it a problem if the code inside a loop takes some time to execute?